# Ruby's "hello world".scan(/(\w){2}/) is not the same as "hello world".scan(/\w{2}/)?

Tags: ruby, regex

I thought I knew `scan` in Ruby: as if it is doing a single match, but repeat it for all results and put into array?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "hello world".scan(/\w{2}/)
 => ["he", "ll", "wo", "rl"] 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "hello world".scan(/(\w){2}/)
 => [["e"], ["l"], ["o"], ["l"]]
```

How come the second line resulted that -- and how do you make it return the same result as line 1?  (because sometimes we have to add `()` to the regex.

---

as a contract, with or without `()`, the following are the same:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "hello world"[/\w{2}/]
 => "he" 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "hello world"[/(\w){2}/]
 => "he"
```

Answer (score 3):

The parens create a match group. Try `/(?:\w){2}/` instead.

Comment: How does this explain the behaviour the OP noted? I don't understand this at all...

Comment: @Tim: It's showing the grouping, but only the last match (i.e. every second letter in a run of two letters) is actually grouped. The fix is to just not group.

Comment: @Ignacio you mean `?:` will not create a group?  This is particular to Ruby?  Are there simpler solutions... such as a different method, or `"hello world"[/\w{2}/g]`... or `"hello world".scan(/(\w){2}/, :top_level)`... something that is in a simple form

Comment: Non-grouping matches via `(?:...)` are found in a number of modern regex engines. As for possible simpler solutions, I don't know enough Ruby to be able to give any.

Comment: @Tim I think the second line in the OP was giving the "final" matched `( )` content... so it ignored the top level matched and use the `( )` being matched twice and used the 2nd one

Comment: Ah, I understand. If there is a group, then `scan` obviously behaves differently than if there isn't a group in the regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found something more:

`scan` seems to work using group if there is any, so that's why the behavior of the 2nd line was like that.  (using the last matched content inside `( )` and use that in the results inside the array.)

As a test:  (if there are multiple groups, then all groups go into one array)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "hello world".scan(/((\w){2})/)
 => [["he", "e"], ["ll", "l"], ["wo", "o"], ["rl", "l"]]
```

This is a way to get it: alway add top level `( )`, and use `map` to get the first element in array (ie, the top level match):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "hello world".scan(/((\w){2})/).map {|e| e.first}
 => ["he", "ll", "wo", "rl"]
```

But I would still like to find simpler answer...